# GROUP BY Problem

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a SQL Server 2005 table called Users:

```
UserID | Date        | Name | Issues | On    | Off   | Value
1      | 02/02/2010  | John | 3      | True  | False | 75
2      | 07/23/2010  | Nate | 7      | False | True  | 50
3      | 02/12/2010  | John | 5      | False | True  | 45
4      | 01/29/2010  | John | 8      | True  | False | 65
5      | 09/01/2010  | Nate | 6      | True  | False | 30
6      | 12/07/2010  | John | 2      | False | True  | 40
7      | 07/18/2010  | Nate | 10     | True  | False | 80
```

I want to get the SUM of Issues for each Name, the SUM of Value when On is true, the SUM of Value when Off is true between given dates:

```
Name | No of issues| SUM of ON | SUM of OFF
John | 18          | 140       | 85
Nate | 23          | 110       | 50
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are your "On" and "Off" columns mutually exclusive? Oh and any chance you could format your question a bit clearer, makes it very hard to read as is.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
SELECT Users.[NAME], 
       SUM(Users.Issues) As Issues, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Users.[On] THEN Users.[Value] ELSE 0 END) AS On, 
       SUM(Case WHEN Users.[Off] THEN Users.[Value] ELSE 0 END) As Off 
FROM Users 
GROUP BY Users.[NAME]
```

Comment: I want the SUM of Value column when ON is TRUE and when OFF is true.

Comment: Sorry, I just notices that myself (was too busy in decrypting the original question, thanks for editing, btw)

Comment: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'.

Comment: I've added "='True'" in the CASE part! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    Name, 
    SUM(issues),
    SUM(CASE [On] WHEN 1 THEN Value ELSE 0 END) 'Sum ON',
    SUM(CASE [On] WHEN 0 THEN Value ELSE 0 END) 'Sum OFF'
FROM 
    dbo.testuser
GROUP BY
    Name
```

This does give me the desired output you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Typically one doesn't find two columns, one called ON and the other called OFF, in a table, because they're usually mutually exclusive states and two columns would permit both to be True.  Normally all you'd need is one column called ON which can be set to False to indicate the off-state. So what is going on here with your table is not really clear.

If On and Off are indeed mutually exclusive states and you've simply done things in a goofy way, then the best way to get into a result-set rows that are on-state and rows that are off-state is to use a UNION.

```
           select {desired columns for rows that are on), sum(value) as YourSum
           where on=true
           group by  {group-by column(s)}
           UNION
           select {desired columns for rows that are off}, sum(value) as YourSum
           where off=true
           group by {group-by column(s)}
```

You could also create two persistent views, one for the On rows and the other for Off Rows and UNION selects against them.

If you want separate columns using the above UNION approach, you can create a dummy column, a subquery, and feed the sums through a bogus aggregate MAX() function:

```
          select name, max( OnSum) as OnSummed, max( OffSum) as OffSummed from
          (

          select name, sum(value) as OnSum, 0 as OffSum
          from mytable
          where on= true
          group by name
          union
          select name, 0 as OnSum, sum(value) as OffSum
          from mytable
          where off=true
          group by name

          )
          group by name
```

Comment: I can't change the table.. It was designed this way! :)

Comment: Fair enough. Not you, but somebody else has done things maybe in a goofy way. :-)

Comment: OK -- I see that your ON and OFF are not mutually exclusive. A row can have both values to true.  Requires a different approach.